# Kconfig choice: non-selected choices shown as new

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot, kbuild

I have the following Kconfig code:

```
choice
    prompt "Choice ?"
    config A_CHOSEN
          bool "A"
    config B_CHOSEN
           bool "B"
 endchoice
```

My problem, everytime i run make oldconfig it says:

```
*
* Restart config...
*
Choice ?
> 1. A (A_CHOSEN)
  2. B (B_CHOSEN) (NEW)
choice[1-2]:
```

I checked the config file and it says

```
A_CHOSEN=y
# B_CHOSEN is not set
```

Any idea why the not selected option is always shown as new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

For unknown reason, the buildroot maintainers have decided to patch conf to only read in variables prefixed with BR2_

Answer (score 0):

When you run make oldconfig. It reads the existing .config file and ask the user for any new additions to the config file and mark it as new. This is very useful when you upgrade to a new kernel, as it lets you make a decision for each new configuration parameter.

Comment: Yes, but in my case it detects options as new, that aren't.